# C++ program doesn't print out strings but does output double value

Tags: c++, string, double, output

So here is the program I'm working on. So far it just prints out the double value in my CPP file. Note the two characters arrays I have set up. Why is this?

#### Molecule.h

```
const int MAX_STRUCT = 10;
const int MAX_NAME = 20;

class Molecule {
    char molecule_structure[];
    char molecule_name[];
    double molecule_mass;
 public: 
    Molecule();
    bool read();
    void display() const;
};
```

#### Molecule.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "Molecule.h"

Molecule::Molecule() {

molecule_structure[0] = '\0';
molecule_name[0] = '\0';
molecule_mass = 0;

}

bool Molecule::read(){

bool complete = false;

    cout << "Enter structure : ";
    cin.getline (molecule_structure, 10);

    if (strcmp (molecule_structure, "0") != 0){

    cout << "Enter full name : ";
    cin.getline (molecule_name, 20);

    cout << "Enter weight : ";
    cin >> molecule_mass;

    cin.ignore();
    complete = true;       
}

else {

molecule_structure[0] = '\0';
molecule_name[0] = '\0';
molecule_mass = 0;

}

return complete;

}


void Molecule::display() const
{       
cout << molecule_structure << "       " << molecule_name  << "       " << molecule_mass     << endl;
}
```

#### w4x.h

```
 const int MAX_MOLECULES = 10;
```

#### w4x.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 #include "w4x.h"
 #include "Molecule.h"

 int main() {
 int n = MAX_MOLECULES;
 Molecule molecule[MAX_MOLECULES];

 cout << "Molecular Information\n";
 cout << "=====================" << endl;

 for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MOLECULES; i++) {
     if (!molecule[i].read()) {
         n = i;
         i = MAX_MOLECULES;
     }
     cout << endl;
 }

 cout << "Structure            Name                     Mass\n";
 cout << "==================================================" << endl;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     molecule[i].display();
 }
```

The errors I believe are coming from my Molecule.cpp file which is what I've been changing around.
This is the output I'm currently receiving.

```
Molecular Information

=====================

Enter structure : Super 
Enter full name : Man
Enter weight : 57

Enter structure : 0

Structure            Name                     Mass
==================================================
              57
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  You shouldn't be using `char molecule_structure[];` in your class; you should probably be using strings, and failing that, you should be using sized character arrays such as `char molecule_structure[64];`.  Whether that's the source of your trouble is a different matter, but it should be looked at hard.

Comment: Q: How much memory have you allocated for the char arrays? A:None If you don't understand char arrays and pointers then std::string will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the header `Molecule.h` so it uses:

```
const int MAX_STRUCT = 10;
const int MAX_NAME = 20;

class Molecule {
    char molecule_structure[MAX_STRUCT];
    char molecule_name[MAX_NAME];
    double molecule_mass;
 public: 
    Molecule();
    bool read();
    void display() const;
};
```

Makes the code work sanely.

---

A more thorough reworking of the code to use `std::string` gives:

#### Molecule.h

```
#ifndef MOLECULE_H_INCLUDED
#define MOLECULE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
class Molecule
{
  std::string molecule_structure;
  std::string molecule_name;
  double molecule_mass;
public:
  Molecule();
  bool read();
  void display() const;
};

#endif // MOLECULE_H_INCLUDED
```

#### Molecule.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "Molecule.h"

Molecule::Molecule() : molecule_structure(""), molecule_name(""), molecule_mass(0) { }

bool Molecule::read()
{
  Molecule m;

  cout << "Enter structure : ";
  if (!getline(cin, m.molecule_structure) || m.molecule_structure == "")
    return false;

  cout << "Enter full name : ";
  if (!getline(cin, m.molecule_name))
    return false;

  cout << "Enter weight    : ";
  if (!(cin >> m.molecule_mass))
    return false;

  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

  swap(*this, m);

  return true;
}

void Molecule::display() const
{
  cout << left << setw(15) << molecule_structure << "      ";
  cout << left << setw(20) << molecule_name      << "      ";
  cout << setprecision(5)  << molecule_mass      << endl;
}
```

The `read()` function does not modify the variable it is given unless the reading is successful.  There are probably better ways to handle the input, but that shown is reasonably sensible.  You terminate the input with an empty line in response to the '`Enter structure:`' prompt.  The `printf()` format notations have the merit of brevity compared with what's necessary with C++ I/O streams.

#### w4x.cpp

No longer including `w4x.h`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Molecule.h"

const int MAX_MOLECULES = 10;

int main()
{
   int n = MAX_MOLECULES;
   Molecule molecule[MAX_MOLECULES];

   cout << "Molecular Information\n";
   cout << "=====================" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MOLECULES; i++) {
     if (!molecule[i].read()) {
       n = i;
       break;
     }
     cout << endl;
   }

   if (n > 0)
   {
     cout << "Structure            Name                      Mass\n";
     cout << "===================================================" << endl;

     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       molecule[i].display();
   }
 }
```

Comment: This would work. But you would also want to use these constants with the user input, otherwise future changes might introduce buffer overflow conditions.

Comment: No, it makes the code explode just as before when someone decides to input a name longer than 20 characters. Such code is the surest way to disaster! Use either C++ strings or allocate dynamic memory according to the required size manually, but do not require users to know what arbitrary limits you have coded into your program!

Comment: @Sqeaky: ugh; you mean you want me to read all the code?  Yes, you're right, the 10 and 20 in the `Molecule::read()` function should probably be `sizeof(molecule_structure)` and `sizeof(molecule_name)` or, failing that, the constants `MAX_STRUCT` and `MAX_NAME`.  That's just 'minimum necessary change' stuff.  It would still be better to use `std::string` to store the names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sizeof does make more sense, I was just advocating consistency.